# How to perform a bilinear interpolation for an area

Tags: python, math

I have a netCDF File which shows surface runoff from 1850 to 2014. I took a slice to show the runoff in a specific area, and the resulting plot gives me four regions which may have different runoff values, depending on the date. I wanted to use bilinear interpolation to find the runoff at the point 282,43.5.
How would I set up the code to do this?
What I have so far is:

```
file='D:\\mrros_Eday_IPSL-CM6A-LR_land-hist_r1i1p1f1_gr_18500101-20141231.nc'

dset = xr.open_dataset(file, decode_times=True, use_cftime=True)
latbounds = (42,45) # (min, max)
lonbounds = (280, 282.5) # (min, max)

#lets say i take the plot at this particular date
dset['mrros'].sel(time=cftime.DatetimeGregorian(1850, 7, 22, 12, 0, 0, 0),lat=slice(*latbounds),lon=slice(*lonbounds)).plot()
plt.show()

array=dset['mrros'].sel(time=cftime.DatetimeGregorian(1850, 7, 22, 12, 0, 0, 0),lat=slice(*latbounds),lon=slice(*lonbounds))
#I can see the runoff values of each section but how would I use this too take a binomial interpolation.
```

Comment: Would it be possible to explain your question with geometric terms that wouldn't require any knowledge about netCDF and runoffs to be understood?

Comment: Can you share the netCDF file? Otherwise I would suggest cdo (climate data operators) for the task as that tool can natively interpolate your data very fast.